# How do I change my photos in square size in instafeed?

Tags: plugins, instagram, instagram-api

I use instafeed plugin on my website. Since June 1, 2016, Instagram API change their settings. The photos change to different sizes. How do I change it back like before? I want it to look like square size.

These are my instafeed settings:

```
var bravesMinimal = new Instafeed({
    target: 'tab1',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'mytagname',
    userId: xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    accessToken: 'xxxx',
    limit: 12,
    resolution: 'low_resolution',
    template: '<div class="insta-wrap"><img src="{{image}}" /><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><div class="likes-wrap"><div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div></div></a></div>',
    after: function() {
        if (!this.hasNext()) {
            myButton.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can protect square size with adding css like this for example:

```
#instafeed a img{
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
}
```